# PostgreSQL function multiple rows returned from subquery in case statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1, case-when

So I have written a postgreSQL function that is supposed to do a search on a table based on a huge amount of optional input parameters which i group with lots of AND statements. This one however:

```
AND
(
 (newcheck IS NULL) 
    OR
    ( 
    newcheck IS NOT NULL AND product.id IN(
    CASE WHEN newcheck='New' 
        THEN
        (SELECT product.id FROM product WHERE product.anew IS true)
    ELSE
        (SELECT product.id from product WHERE product.anew IS false)
    END)
    )
)
```

gives me a

```
ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
```

This isnt helping much since I do want it to return a lot more than one row.
The values of the newcheck variable will be sent from a dropdown menu in a web form so it can only be 'New' or 'Old'.
Any ideas on what might be causing this problem?

Comment: The problem - every subselect returns more than one row and `CASE` statement expects one result in every branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
AND ((newcheck IS NULL)
     OR (newcheck IS NOT NULL 
         AND product.id IN (SELECT product.id 
                            FROM product 
                            WHERE product.anew = CASE WHEN newcheck='New' 
                                                      THEN true 
                                                      ELSE false
                                                 END))
```

Comment: Alright that seems to work perfectly when I set the newcheck to anything but 'New'. In the case where it is 'New' I only get one row as a result...